# How to change automatically the filter criterion in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set-up, thanks to an option button, a filter on my data in Excel?

I have a maturity date and I want to exclude with this filter all the expired items.

The cell A3 is giving me the date of today with the Excel function Today().

I know that this is working:

```
Sub OptionButton6_Click()
  Rows("12:12").Select
  Selection.AutoFilter
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$AK$175").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
     ">12/09/2016" , Operator:=xlAnd
  Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

And I have tried this :

```
Sub OptionButton6_Click()
  Rows("12:12").Select
  Selection.AutoFilter
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$AK$175").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
      A3, Operator:=xlAnd
  Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

with A3 being this : `=CONCATENATE(">",TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yyyy"))`

Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance,
Trancavel

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$AK$175").AutoFilter Field:=7, _
     Criteria1:= ">" & DateValue(Now()), Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: Thanks! The code works but not completely. Now, when I apply the macro, everything is filtered. I have no data. However, if I go in "Data filters", the good filter is set-up and when I validate again, the good data is displayed. Could it be a problem of date format?

Comment: Could be, depends on whether your worksheet contains actual Date values, or strings which *look like date values*. There's a difference, and I suspect that is the root of your problem either way.

Comment: I verified and everything and this column's values are formatted as Date. Your code is automatically creating the filter and I can activate it manually. However, it does not display anything when it runs through the macro. I really don't understand.

Comment: *formatted* as date, or *actually* a date? If you check `[A12].Value` in VBE, does it give you a long integer? Or a date string?

Comment: It's giving me a date string.

Comment: Shoot, my mistake. That doesn't actually tell us anything about the underlying value. Impossible to fully answer without knowing what type of data is actually residing in the workbook. Screenshots of your data and especially of the filter dialog would probably help.

Comment: Ok Thank you! I solved the issue. It was in date format but in dd/mm/yyyy and apparently, Excel is not really happy about it. So I did `Format(DateValue(Now()),"yyyy-mm-dd")` and it works fine. Thank you for all your help and time!